# Caddyfile rewrite /foo /bar#locationOnPage

Tags: caddy

I am trying to rewrite a path from foo to bar with a page anchor tag in the url like such
`rewrite /foo /bar#locationOnPage`

I have also tried using redir and uri replace, but kinda stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that the #anchortag part of a url is kept by the browser and never sent to the server so I'm not sure if it is possible to rewrite to a #url.

You could try a redirect which may be what you wish.

Perhaps @whitestrake might have more info.  The [caddy forums](https://caddy.community/) are a great place to ask these sorts of questions